# fast grid to handle specific operation (selecting and coloring cells)

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a task to rewrite in c# a program made in delphi (lost sources).
The user creates a grid with a lot of columns and rows (10-200 of each) and paints the grid cells into red (by double clicking).

Example of the grid: [image]

The basic datagridview (windows forms) and datagrid (wpf) lag with such quantity of elements and selection is very slow compared to delphi program. In the delphi program the selection is instaneous.

Can you, please, suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: You should probably try posting your own code first, and also specifying what kind of speeds you're looking for. The data grid might be fast enough, your code might be the problem, but it is difficult to tell without any additional information.

Comment: I create a control from toolbox and simply fill it in a cycle: add 200 columns and 200 rows with very small width. The selection (with a mouse) is not instaneous. Maybe you can provide a code where selection on so much cells doesn't lag? I didn't succeed in finding an answer unfortunately.